# distribution according to random measures

Tags: probability, probability-theory, measure-theory, random-variables, random

Is a random probability measure a probability measure, i.e. if $X_i$ is random variable on some probability space $(\Omega,\mathcal F,\mathbb P)$ could its induced distribution be a random probability measure $\mu$, say $X_i\sim \mu$?

Then, as $\mu$ is itself random, it has an own probability distribution, $\mu\sim Q$.

For example let's take the empirical measure $P_n(A)=\frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=1}^n \delta_{X_i}(A)$. Then the empirical distribution function $F_n(x):=\frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=1}^n 1\{X_i\le x\}$ is a random probability measure as it is an empirical measure indexed by the class $\mathcal C=\{(-\infty,x]: x\in \mathbb R\}$? Can one say $X_i\sim P_n$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For a random measure, it is just the case that $\Omega = \mathcal{P}$ the set of all probability measures on space. For example $P_n$ in your definition.

The empirical measure is a random variable on the space of functions. This measure is obtained via taking the push forward measure of the mapping $\pi: \mathcal{P}(\mathbb{R}) \mapsto \mathcal{S}$, where $\mathcal{S}$ is the collection of step functions in $\mathbb{R}$.

$X\sim \mu$ is for a fixed measure $\mu$. In your example, you cannot say $X_i \sim P_n$ because the distribution $X_i$'s is something from which you have drawn the random variables $X_i$'s to construct the measure in the first place ($P_n$ is just a function of $X_i$'s). But, if you wanted mean that $X$ is a "sample" from the empirical measure, then you have to keep in mind that there are two steps of randomness. The first step to construct the measure, and the second is taking a sample from $P_n$ conditionally on the $X_i$'s in the first step. So one needs to write the distribution of $X$ using a conditional distribution.

Comment: Consider you have a sample $X=(X_1,\dots, X_n).$ Now assume $X_i\mid \mu \sim \mu$ and $\mu\sim Q$, where $\mu$ is a random probability measure and $Q$ is the Distribution of the random probability measure. I think that is an example for the "two steps of randomness" you talked about. Can you explain what $X_i\mid \mu \sim \mu$ means and why we can't use/ what's the difference to $X_i\sim \mu$? Many thanks!

Comment: The conditional distribution will be a discrete measure. Suppose you toss a coin 6 times and you get TTHTTH. So your empirical measure $P_n$ will give mass 1/3 on head and 2/3 on tail. But $X_1$ is Bernoulli$(1/2)$. What you can do is take a new coin with respect to the observed empirical measure. The outcome  $Y$ will be Bernoulli $(1/3)$ conditional on the event that there are exactly $2$ heads among $(X_1,\dots,X_6)$.